# Condoms and forbidden relations

Tags: halacha, sexuality

If one wears a condom, since it prevents actual "skin-to-skin" contact, would this prevent forbidden relations? I am not asking about wasted seed, but just the relation itself. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Maharsham, Rogatchover Gaon and Rav Ovadia Yosef all rule that even with a condom it is called sexual relations. Interestingly, the Rabbi Dovid Lau (a nobody compared to the heavy hitters mentioned above) has a piece in his sefer where he calls into question some of the halachik mechanics in this case, but even he stops short of saying that it's not called relations.

(source: [המקום מרחק](http://daf-yomi.com/BookFiles.aspx?type=1&id=291) על מסכת יבמות ג' ע"ב)

Comment: לא עיינתי בתשובות שהביא שם, אבל מה שדימה באותו ספר ביאה ע׳י קונדום להביאה דרך סדין ריש ירושלמי מס׳ יבמות, נראה שזה טעוס גמור. עין פני משה וציון ירושלים שם.

Comment: כעת עיינתי במהרש׳ם וצפנת פענח וב׳ה שכיונתי, אמת שמעשה זה אסור מיהו הם אמרו שאין ענין זה דומה לדרך סדין.   ועדיין איני יכול למצוא איפו בתשו׳ שואל ומשיב מדבר בזה.

Comment: Reb Chaim and @user6591 -- do you have more specific מראה מקומות?

Comment: @Shokhet click on his link to that seffer. In note 11 on daf ג ע׳ב he has the mareh makomos.

Comment: No mention of rav chaim over??

Comment: Where is the teshuva from R' Ovadia found?

Comment: The Chief Rabbi of Israel is a nobody? Do you really need to say that?

Comment: Yes. I think that he himself would concur.

Comment: "A nobody compared...." Not necessary. No one reading this answer is interested in the Rabbi's league table... Really stains an otherwise top answer.

Comment: He may concur to that, he's got ענווה - but why call him so in the first place?

Comment: does any rav rules different?